# Onclick or Hover Functions in a Google Doc

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I created a custom dialog box on a Google document but I don't want it to open when the document is opened.  Instead I want the box to appear when a certain word is clicked or hovered over.  I don't want links to other documents. Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried? Instead of just asking for implementation, show us the effort from your part. Also what programming language are you using? Or are you just referring to working with Google Doc files itself?

Comment: I don't know anything about coding, so I can't tell you what language I'm using.  Here is the code I found online and copied/pasted
function onOpen() {
 DocumentApp.getUi()
 .createMenu('Custom Dialog')
 .addItem('Show dialog', 'showDialog')
 .addToUi();
}

function showDialog() {
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('2_1VocabListHTML')
 .setWidth(300)
 .setHeight(200);
 DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, '2.1');
}

Comment: I tried replacing "onopen" with "onclick"